# SQLite : placing an array of strings in a TEXT column and maching the line with an element of the array

Tags: sql, arrays, sqlite, match

How do i get an element of an array of strings I placed in an SQLite3 column ?

I have this SQLite3 table : Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pseudos TEXT witch contains the id of a user and the list of pseudos he uses :

```
0|Bob, Avee  
1|Test, Alice, Frank  
2|Boby, Robert  
3|Avebee, Bob
```

How do I get all lines that have the peudo "Bob" and not "Boby" ?   When trying LIKE "%Bob%", I obviously match "Boby" witch I wish to avoid.

note : the 'pseudos' column can hold an unfined number of speudos witch are separated by a ", ". The separator can be changed.
There are no spaces in the pseudos

Comment: Which SQL Server version do you use?

Comment: I am using SQLite3 but I would like to know if there is a solution that would work on all SQL

Comment: @oryol, who said it was SQL Server?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: *on all SQL* - sql syntax may vary among different DB management systems

Comment: thanks, I will change the tags

Comment: how shoud I separate the strings if commas are a bad plan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the issue here is a non-1NF design and how to make that database-independent.  I could imagine solving this on SQLite or PostgreSQL but coming up with a good, performent solution on both is unlikely to be easy or worth the time to do.

In SQLite I would look at the FT3 and FT4 extensions for indexes tat might support infix in like clauses efficiently.  You can use trigram indexes in PostgreSQL to achieve something similar but with a lot more extra checking so may not be an adequate answer there.

In PostgreSQL I would store an array of terms and use GIN indexes to solve this but that is not readily supported on SQLite.

So your best option for database neutrality is normalization and to store the pseudos in another table.  Then it is just a join.  Otherwise you will have to build a different solution for every database you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to create separate table with UserId and Pseudo (one by row) and join with it for searching.

Comment: I cannot edit the table so the solution is not viable

Answer (score 1):

In case the Oracle DB and SQLite, use the substr and the direct instr in the like

`SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(pseudos, INSTR(pseudos, ' ')+1)) LIKE UPPER('%Bob%');`

Comment: select * from test where pseudos = SUBSTR(pseudos, INSTR(pseudos, ' ')+1) LIKE '%Bob%'; does not give anything, am I not applying your solution correctly ? ( tried "%BOB%", "%Bob%" and "%bob%" without any results, tried just '%' and got everything )

Comment: To solve the problem of uppercase and lowercase use the UPPER.

SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(pseudos, INSTR(pseudos, ' ')+1)) LIKE UPPER('%Bob%');

Comment: it work a bit more but only maches "Aveebee, Bob", not "Bob, Avee"

Comment: [edited] after adding more lines to test, it seems it maches Bob correctly but not on beginning of lines

Comment: Would adding a condition to match the begginning of the line be a good idea ?

Comment: Will make the comparison after the comma, in your case only the last bob

Comment: You can control the index by INSTR